# Technical English terms used in Homebrewing

Tags: terminology

Do you know a site or a web page that lists and explains all technical English terms specific to homebrewing?

I am Italian and I would like learning more in this field, but sometimes I do not understand all terms used here.

PS. Maybe could be an idea have a CW to fullfill this purpose?

Comment: Don't worry, most native English speakers need to consult some literature to learn some of the specific terms; such as mash, sparge, lauder, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [this glossary](http://beeradvocate.com/beer/101/terms.php) by [BeerAdvocate](http://beeradvocate.com/).