# Homebrewing Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms

Tags: terminology

**What are the common phrases, words, abbreviations that are used by home brewers on this site or in conversation?**

In the interest of keeping content on this site, rather than [linking elsewhere](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/684/technical-english-terms-used-in-homebrewing), this is a list of common home brewing terms that may not be English or common usage in English.  Inspired by and largely derived from [this SO meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms), though I've left off most of the "crowd control" stuff - we can add it back if it's necessary.

#### Please:

- Edit the existing answer
- Insert relevant links to more detailed information on the term/phrase/abbreviation
- Add only factual information
- Keep it very, very brief, terse, and to the point
- Delete your own comments once they become irrelevant (integrated into the glossary)
- Use the Edit Summary box to note reasons for your edit, not comments

#### Please avoid:

- Opinion
- Using abbreviations, terms, and phrases inside a description
- Unverified information
- Uncommon terms, abbreviations, phrases
- Long descriptions
- Unnecessary detail
- Citations or examples of usage
- Inside jokes that are not related to home brewing
- Common Internet jargon (i.e., IMHO, TL;DR, RTFM, etc.) unless usage here differs significantly

Comment: I feel this should definitely be a wiki. Also, doesn't the site already have a list of tags with brief descriptions and longer wiki pages for brewing terms?

Comment: Agreed - I'm unable to set my own question as a wiki, though I can set the answer.  And it does, though not every term is a tag & vice-versa.  Maybe we could restrict this to non-tagged terms?

Comment: This is just going to turn into a big list of tags that we already have, for the most part.  Just go edit the tags if they don't explain what you want, or make new ones if what you're looking for doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

#### Beer

> The finished product of home brewing using primarily malted barley, water, hops and yeast.  The product does not need to be carbonated to be considered beer, in that case it is "flat beer".

#### DME

> Dry Malt Extract

#### Fermentation

> The process of converting sugars (carbohydrates) to alcohol.

#### Gravity

> See: Specific Gravity

#### Hops

> The female flowers of the plant, Humulus Lupulus.  Used for bittering & aroma in most beers.

#### LDME

> Light Dry Malt Extract.  A powdered, dry extract of a lightly malted barley, such as Pilsener Malt.

#### LME

> Liquid Malt Extract.  A liquid, gooey concentrate of malted barley.

#### RDWHAHB

> Relax; Don't Worry; Have a home brew!  An abbreviation usually used to let a poster know that there is nothing to worry about.

#### Specific Gravity

> The ratio of the density of a fluid in relation to another.  In brewing terms it is usually used to refer to the dissolved sugar content before & after fermentation (original/starting gravity and final gravity, respectively).

#### Wort

> Name given to beer before fermentation has begun.

#### Wyeast

> A commercial supplier of yeast products.  [Wyeast web site](http://www.wyeastlab.com/).

#### Yeast

> A single-celled fungus that ferments wort into beer.